# Spring Security tag lib not working with JSF

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, spring-security

I want to use springboot with security and primefaces.

I have followed [this article](https://codenotfound.com/jsf-primefaces-spring-security-example.html) but with one little change, **I don't want to use `JoinFaces`**. Everything works fine except the spring sec taglib.
`xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags`

Now I'm not sure how to configure `servletContext` so that the **sec tags** would work.

[Here is GitHub repo](https://github.com/p500plus/springboot-with-security-and-primefaces) for now its really simple project just to test the combination SB + SS + PF.

Comment: So if you create a simple example with plain jsf and no primefaces it works?

Comment: And please improve your title. It now is a concatenation of the tags... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Sort of not helpful

Comment: No it doesn't work either there should be some kind of configuration but i dont realy know where and what... :-/ Sorry fot the title hope it is better now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same scenario before and I ended up adding `springsecurity.taglib.xml` in my project. You can copy the file content from [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/2.3.x/reference/html/spring-faces.html#spring-faces-security-taglib) and then register it in your `web.xml` file as follow:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```